# Why is my javascript/html document bypassing my attempt to check if a string is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Edit: |SOLVED| user Jaromanda X's solution worked perfectly. Thank you**

My goal is to have the user enter a bit of text into the textbox and submit it. I want to check and see if the textbox is empty and, if so, it should alert the user that a name needs to be entered. If it is *not* empty I want it to display the text they had entered.

The issue is this: Every time I hit submit it takes the value of the textbox - empty or not - and displays it without ever alerting the user of an empty text field. I feel like I'm missing something very basic. Thank you for your help!

HTML File

```
<body>
    <div id="statusBar">
        <h1 id="playerName"></h1>
        <h2 id="playerHP"></h2>
    </div>

    <div id="gameWindow">
       Player Name: <input id="inputName" type="text" name="Player Name">
       <br>
       <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="getStats()";>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS File

```
function getStats(){

if(document.getElementById("inputName").len === " "){
    alert('You must enter a name!');
} else {
        var playerHP = 10;
        var playerName = document.getElementById('inputName').value;

        //Display player name on screen
        document.getElementById('playerName').innerHTML = playerName;

        //remove the value placed in the text box
        document.getElementById('inputName').value = "";

        //Display the player's HP
        document.getElementById('playerHP').innerHTML = playerHP;
    }
};
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("inputName")` does not have a property called `.len` and it certainly would never be a space if it existed - you probably want `document.getElementById("inputName").value.lenght === 0`

Comment: That fixed it, exactly! I'm new to coding outside of HTML and CSS so I'm not familiar with it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: So @JaromandaX answers the question in a comment and a bunch of people jump in, copying that to their "answer" hoping to get the rep. Why not, all the cool kids are doing it. (oh, and you might want to `trim()` the value before checking its `length`, in case someone entered just a bunch of spaces.)

Comment: @StephenP Sounds about right! I'm just glad it was something so silly on my part. Also glad this site exists

Comment: Yeah, I may have answered in a comment, only because I was looking for a viable duplicate to this question - similar questions have been asked many times :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I know =/ I had spent a fair bit of time combing through similar questions but I wasn't wrapping my head around what I was missing for whatever reason

Comment: it's all good @BoomTownWhale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your if statement to:

```
if (document.getElementById("inputName").value.length === 0) {
```

Right now you're trying to get a property `len` of your `<input>` element, which doesn't exist. You should first be getting the *value* of the input, and checking if its length is zero. Hence, `.value.length`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
if (document.getElementById("inputName").value === "") {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the right conditional.

Replace the

```
document.getElementById("inputName").len
```

with

`document.getElementById("inputName").value.length === 0`.